# Pandas join string contains and loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know if this is possible on pandas:

It's easier to see in image what I want:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV5fy.png

Comment: `df1.loc[df1['word'].str.contains(''start with A')]` ?  it would be better if you gave a sample of your dataframe with your expected output

Comment: Sure, just a minute and I'll do a better definition

Comment: `str.contains` has a `case` argument set it to `True` if you want to match by case

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following approach:

```py
# Select only target patterns in df1
df1 = df1[df1.Description.str.contains('|'.join(df2.Description))].reset_index(drop=True)
# Select only target patterns in df2
df2 = df2[df2.Description.map(lambda x: df1.Description.str.contains(x).any())].reset_index(drop=True)
# Concatenate dataframes
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2.rename(columns={'Description': 'Description (df2)'})], axis=1)
```

---

Another approach, perhaps not very efficient for large dataframes:

```py
mapper = {k:v for k in df1.Description for v in df2.Description if v in k}

df3 = pd.concat([
    df1[df1.Description.isin(mapper.keys())].reset_index(drop=True),
    df2[df2.Description.isin(mapper.values())].rename(columns={'Description': 'Description (df2)'}).reset_index(drop=True)
], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and hope for the best